# QT Labels: Updating Label with Images

Tags: image, qt, label

Hello I am using QT to load in images to a GUI.
I can easily load in one file into one label.
The issues arise when I want to load in a new image into that same label.
In essence I want to update that label.
I am trying to do it by pressing a button using SetPixmap as the slot function.
However a direct call using SetPixmap works but when it is in a slot it does not work for me.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <qdebug>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QTcore>

using namespace std;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QImage Hellkite_Tyrant;
    Hellkite_Tyrant.load(":/MtGimages/HT.jpg");

    QImage Island;
    Island.load(":/MtGimages/Island.jpg");

    if(Hellkite_Tyrant.isNull())
    {
        ui->textlabel->setText("Did not work");
    }
    //ui->myLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Hellkite_Tyrant));
    ui->myLabel->hide();



    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),
            ui->myLabel,SLOT(setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Hellkite_Tyrant))));

    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),
            ui->myLabel,SLOT(show()));

   // connect(ui->pushButton_2,SIGNAL(clicked()),
    //        ui->myLabel,SLOT(setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Island))));

   // connect(ui->pushButton_2,SIGNAL(clicked()),
   //         ui->myLabel,SLOT(repaint()));

   // connect(ui->pushButton_2,SIGNAL(clicked()),
   //         ui->myLabel,SLOT(show()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot.
Hence, these is something wrong in this code piece.

```
connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),
        ui->myLabel,SLOT(setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Hellkite_Tyrant))));
```

You should do it like this.

```
// mainwindow.h

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
...

protected slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

...
};

// mainwindow.cpp

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
...

    connect(ui->pushButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),
            this, SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->myLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(Hellkite_Tyrant));
    ui->myLabel->show();
}
```